# How to fetch Show As value of an EkEvent type object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I am fetching object of type EkEvent from event store, but I am not able to find Show As property for the event.

Note: We can set Show As = Free/Busy, while we create or edit event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, I am posting it here , it might be useful to someone.

```
[eventObj availability]; //returns the "Show As" property for event

typedef enum {
   EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported = -1,
   EKEventAvailabilityBusy = 0,
   EKEventAvailabilityFree,
   EKEventAvailabilityTentative,
   EKEventAvailabilityUnavailable
} EKEventAvailability;
```